# Change inputText on dataTable selection JSF 2.2/ Primefaces

Tags: java, jsf, primefaces

i have a question Regarding JSF 2.2/ Primefaces.

I want to set the value of an inputText depending on the selected Object in a dataTable.The problem is, that the function "rowSelect()" doesn't get called when i select an object from the dataTable.

```
//Target (outside of dataTable)
<h:inputText id="carInput" onclick="PF('carListPopup').show();" value="#{carBean.selectedCar.id}" >

//Table
<p:dataTable id="carListTable" var="car" value="#{carBean.carList}" selectionMode="single" selection="#{carBean.selectedCar}" rowKey="#{car.id}">

//Event
 <p:ajax event="rowSelect" listener="#{carBean.rowSelect}" update=":mainForm:addrepair:carInput" process="carListTable" />

//Function on Server
@Named
@RequestScoped
public class CarBean implements Serializable {

Car selectedCar;

  public void rowSelect(SelectEvent selectEvent)
  {
      System.out.println("Row Selected!");
      selectedCar = (Car) selectEvent.getObject();
   }

    public Car getSelectedCar() {
        return selectedCar;
    }

    public void setSelectedCar(Car selectedCar) {
        this.selectedCar = selectedCar;
    }
}
```

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

After i closed my IDE i got a thoughtless lightning.
I had no "h:form" tag around my "h:dataTable".
After i added the  tag the value is now displaying. 
Thanks anyways!